# possibility of transfer from a fixed-term Lecturer to a continuing appointment

Tags: university, job, tenure-track, united-kingdom, lecturer

Recently, I have got an Lecturer position in a UK University. However, when I got the offer letter, it said that "The appointment is for a fixed-term of five years, with the possibility of subsequent transfer to a continuing appointment." It seems to me that this is not a permanent position.

I am wondering how much possible one can transfer to a permanent position after five years. Is it suitable for me to ask this kind of questions to my Head of School? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: is this one of these positions which starts off as mainly research, with the plan that after five years you become permanent if things have gone satisfactorily? I'm vaguely aware of these existing in my own discipline, but they seem to be a relatively recent development

Comment: By way of contrast, the default Lecturer position in my discipline in a UK university has a contract of the form "your continuous employment starts on [this date], and your probationary period will end on [other date]"

Comment: Having done some looking around, your position sounds similar to one of these 5-year RCUK fellowships which are intended/hoped to transition into an indefinite (i.e. permanent) position. Could you confirm if your job offer is of this form?

Comment: In any case, I find it somewhat surprising that having gone for interview, this was not made clear to you at the time, and you should definitely seek clarification on this from the Head of School at the place which has given you an offer

Comment: Downvoting, pending further clarification from the OP about the particular details that would allow one to give a proper answer to the question

Answer (score 4):

I suspect what it means is that if there is a position available you will be welcome to apply for it but you may not get it.

You are certainly entitled to ask the head of school for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should definitely ask the Head of School for clarification of the process.

As an aside, I'm on a similar line at a U.S. school: full-time Lecturer (dedicated service/teaching, no research) with a 5-year clock before being approved for a CCE (Certificate of Continuing Employment, with protections analogous to tenure).

**Note:** The aside is not meant as a prediction of the OP's UK situation, but only to sketch out a wider universe of possibilities (contrast this example to Mark Joshi's prior answer/suspicion). Thereby highlighting the actual answer: OP must inquire at his local institution.

Comment: UK labor law is sufficiently different from US, that I don't think your experience is mm useful here.

Comment: I second @StrongBad: this is UK/EU stuff, and the teaching/research/tenure systems are very different

Comment: @YemonChoi Is most of the EU that similar to the UK?  I have a little knowledge of the UK system, but I was under the impression that it was fairly different from most of Europe.

Comment: My aside was not meant as a prediction of the OP's UK situation. Added a note above to clarify that.

Comment: @Kimball It's different, but some of the constraints/opportunities are a consequence of (interpretations of?) EU directives. See the closing para of http://julesandjames.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/what-did-eu-ever-do-for-us.html

Comment: @YemonChoi: Thanks for that link. I'll point out that the paragraph you highlight actually does suggest a very similar line in the EU/UK to the one I described above: "The widespread RCUK fellowships (5 years of research which converts to an open-ended lecturer position) were one obvious response to the change in the law."

Comment: Daniel, my point was merely that the expectations and norms of UK vs North American academia are very very different, even if the outline of the contracts does look similar. For example, no protections analogous to tenure; far less emphasis on teaching; and so on

Comment: On the other hand, your clarification of your answer makes sense